# How to split columns on basis of length

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-query-store

I have a table of 10 columns,I want to split one column into two columns if length of value of column is  four,otherwise no split,for rest of values it should enter first splitted column.

```
column  Acolumn Bcolumn C

0000    00      00
1111   
1 1
000     000 
0115    01      15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do something conditionally in MS Access.  That usually means `IIF()` or `SWITCH()`, because MS Access does not support the standard `CASE` expression syntax:

```
select t.column,
       iif(len(column) = 4, left(column, 2), column) as columnA,
       iif(len(column) = 4, right(column, 2), NULL) as columnB
from t;
```

Although I don't recommend it, you can also use `union all`:

```
select t.column, t.column as columnA, NULL as columnB
from t
where len(column) <> 4
union all
select t.column, left(t.column, 2) as columnA, right(t.column, 2) as columnB
from t
where len(column) = 4;
```

Comment: these methods are returning three or two or single digit string to second column after split which should not be done...if length <> 4 the digits should be copied only two first column after split....

Comment: @nitisethi . . . Fixed.  Of course, you don't want the value duplicated in that case.

Comment: value should be duplicated in column A not in column B....but for the above both codes it is duplicating in both Column A and Column B

Comment: @nitisethi . . . I fixed the answer.  Are you referring to the newer code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select columnA, 
       case when len(columnA)=4 then left(columnA,2) end as columnB,
       case when len(columnA)=4 then mid(ColumnA,3,2) end as columnC
from tablename
```